# delete attachment for one post without deleting actual attachment post

Tags: ajax, attachments, post-meta, plugin-wp-e-commerce

I'm writing custom ajax calls for media attachments from **FrontEnd**, I have everything read to use, except the actual logic.

I'm using WP E-Commerce plugin, where I want many images for one post. And I want to use thouse images on variose posts.

consider case: I have created product and uploaded 3 images for this product. Now I create another product and use one of the (3) uploaded images as this product image.
Then I go to first product and delete that image I copied for the second product. Of course That will delete it for second product too.
That's why I'm trying to find a solution where I can just unset/uncheck/delete_for_that_post thing.

or maybe I don't get how it works? Could someone direct my to the right direction?

Summery question would sound like this:
Can I use I media attachment for many products?

thanks

Comment: The "reordering" looks like a [different Question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). And for the first part, what are you looking for? Is it an *Un-attaching* function? That's what I get from "unset as attachment", but I don't understand "unset from post media"...

Comment: For example I have a post, and this post contains 5 images, I want to delete this image from this post, but not to delete the attachment at all. I still want to see this attachment in media manager, that's why I used "unset" )